# Error while concatenating a string to variable in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Please Help me with this code, It gives an error of "too many items" in line 3:

```
<xsl:when test=".[@name='Measurement Pallete']">
    <xsl:variable name="controlID" select=".[@name='Measurement Pallete']/Control/@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="control_ID" select="translate($controlID, ' ', '')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="funcName" select="concat('ClassicTab', $control_ID)"/>              
</xsl:when>
```

The input Xml is of the format

```
<window name="">
    <Control id="" type=""/>
    <Control id="" type=""/>
</window>
```

I want that variable funcname should concatenate "HomeTab" before the name of each Control where window name is "Measurement Pallete"

Complete Stylesheet

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//window">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('Windows/', @id,  '.cs')}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current()[@name='Measurement Pallete']">
                        <xsl:variable name="controlID" select="current()[@name='Measurement Pallete']/Control/@id"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="control_ID" select="translate($controlID, ' ', '')"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="funcName" select="concat('ClassicTab', $control_ID)"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="csfile1">
                            <xsl:with-param name="func_name" select="$funcName"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <xsl:call-template name="automationIDs1">
                            <xsl:with-param name="func_name" select="$funcName"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="csfile"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="automationIDs"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please show us the complete stylesheet, the input XML, and the output expected..

Comment: Please show us the complete stylesheet.. Without it we can only guess..

Comment: @LingamurthyCS the templates are very big and create some C# files so I am not sharing that

Comment: Can you try reproducing the issue with a smaller code, and post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `$controlID` spews out 2 values (I am assuming this is xsl 2.0 because of `xsl:result-document`), `Control[1]/@id` and `Control[2]/@id`, the error comes from

```
<xsl:variable name="control_ID" select="translate($controlID, ' ', '')"/>
```

because you can't take more than one sequence as a first argument of `translate`.

Comment: I used a work around so it works now. Thanks all anyways